# Can I instantiate a module with parameters and add methods?

Tags: node.js

I have a method that looks like this:

```
module.exports = function(authKeys) {
    this.callsLeft = 180;
    this.twit = new Twit(authKeys);
    this.tweets = [];
};
```

I can call it like this:

```
var authKeys = {
key: "value"
},
requestSession = require('./requestSession.js')(authKeys);
```

I wish to add a mehtod to this module this is how I would do it if the module was named requestSession.

```
// value.key+' lang:sv since:2016-04-02'
requestSession.prototype.addTweets = function(phrace,callback) {
    console.log('searching for '+phrace);
    callback()
};
```

Comment: Better I think is to require the module `requestSession = require('./requestSession.js');` now extend it `requestSession.prototype.addTweets...` and than call it `requestSession(authKeys);`

Comment: I can't do that, because requestSession = require('./requestSession.js'); happens in another file, I want to define the methods alongside the module.

Comment: OK I got it wrong. Then simply change `module.exports = function` to `function myFunction(){} myFunction.prototype.addTweets =function (){}` and export it `module.exports = myFunction;`  hope this is what you want :)

Comment: yes, but how can I pass a parameter while instantiating that module?

Comment: The same way you did before just change this `function myFunction(params)...`  and use  `require (...)(params);`